# Wrap every 2 divs in an each loop inside a div

Tags: jquery

Client is using visual composer to create a grid of elements, hes got 3 rows, with 4 colums each, and hes going to be adding more rows in the future, so he wants me to create a slider that only displays 2 rows with 4 columns on each slide (responsive to only display 1 column on mobile, buts thats another story)

Anyways, im using an each loop, to grab all the divs from the 3 rows, and insert them into a single slider div. The part im having trouble with is wrapping every 2 divs into one div to create the two rows, then i would float each of those, to create the 4 columns.

Heres what i have so far

```
$.each( $('.slidergrid'), function(i, left) {
    count = 0;
   $('.wf-span-3', left).each(function() {
        var content = $(this).html();

        if (count == 1) {
            $('#slider').append(content+'</div>');

            alert(count);
            count = 0;
        } else {

            $('#slider').append('<div style="border:1px solid #ccc">'+content);

            alert(count);
            count = count + 1;
        }

   });
})
```

Not the most fancy solution, but i tried using a slice function i found here, and keep getting an uncaught error that slice is not defined or something like that. 
.slidergrid is the class i added to the visual composer rows to be able to target them. and #slider is the slideshow div that.

The above code for some reason outputs one element inside the border, on div outside the border, one div inside, one div outside, etc. When im expecting it two output 2 divs inside the border at a time

Any help would be appreciated.

Added a Jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/Ldh2v1nj/

EDIT: i was able to get it to work, but its a bit bloated and has to go thru two loops, i was hoping someone would be able to refactor it for me?

```
    function grabElements(){
    $.each( $('.slidergrid'), function(i, left) {

       $('.wf-span-3', left).each(function() {
            var content = $(this).html();
            $('#slider').append('<div class="slideshow_item" >'+content+'</div>');  
       });
    })
}
function wrapElements(){
        var divs = $("#slider > .slideshow_item");
        for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=2) {
          divs.slice(i, i+2).wrapAll("<div style='width:23%; padding:1%; float:left;'></div>");
        }
}
$.when($.ajax(grabElements())).then(function () {
        wrapElements()
});
```

Comment: do you have a jsfiddle ?

Comment: i do not, developing this localy

Comment: Could you please post the markup ?

Comment: you can view the site here http://tinyurl.com/ohbwhue, the js is exactly as i posted it above. The only difference between the above markup, and what im working on is i added .slidergrid class to each row

Comment: What's so impossibly difficult to create a reduced, minimal, verifiable example? Also, you might be looking at an X-Y problem—there might be a CSS-based solutions for your question other than wrapping every two elements with JS. But without your markup it's difficult to help.

Comment: here you go https://jsfiddle.net/Ldh2v1nj/

Comment: Hi terry or dyno, i was kinda able to find a solution, if you guys could take a look at it, and let me know if theres a better way. Thansk

Answer (score 0):

Check the styles on the output using Chromes developer tools or Firefox's firebug. If any of your 'content' is floated it will pop out of your border.

Comment: No, ive looked at the output, its literaly outputting one inside the bordered div, one outside, one inside, one outside, and so on.... im not really sure how that happening, that the bordered div is opening and closing without adding the second content, but it is